# Vuetify dialog - extremely slow formatting 2.5MB of XML in ACE editor

Tags: xml, vue.js, vuetify.js, ace-editor

I have a Vue/Vuefify project and I'm using the vkbeutify lib to format XML and then display it in the Ace Editor. The Editor opens in a modal dialog (full screen mode) and all works fairly well when the amount of XML is small.

I have to parse about 2.5MB+ of it (about 2,500,000 characters when formatted in Notepad++) and then Ace becomes unusable (it eventually displays the XML, but it takes a very long time).

I created a simple test page with a textarea and the Editor and the formatting and display goes extremely fast. The page does exactly the same thing as this: https://www.webtoolkitonline.com/xml-formatter.html (this uses Ace and vkbeautify to format xml)

I tried pre-formatting the XML in an text area before passing it to the child dialog, tried subverting Vue and populating the editor container in the mounted() function by getting the DOM contents directly.

Standalone test page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>ACE in Action</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">#editor {position: absolute;top: 0;right: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;}</style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://pagecdn.io/lib/ace/1.4.5/ace.js" integrity="sha256-5Xkhn3k/1rbXB+Q/DX/2RuAtaB4dRRyQvMs83prFjpM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/vkbeautify/vkbeautify.0.99.00.beta.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 500px;">
<div id="editor">
    <tag><inner_tag>sce to aux</inner_tag></tag>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<form>
    <textarea id="xml"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tag><inner_tag>hi</inner_tag></tag></textarea>
    <fieldset><input type="button" id="format" value="Format"></fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/cobalt");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/xml");
    $( function() {
        $( "#format").click(
            async function() {
                var content = document.getElementById("xml").value;
                try {
                    editor.setValue(  content  );
                    editor.setValue( vkbeautify.xml( editor.getValue()  ) );
                } catch( err ) {
                    alert( "Your document is invalid" );
                }
            }
        );
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Vue component:

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <b>Open In Editor </b>
    <v-btn icon color="transparent" depressed small @click="openInEditor()"><v-icon color="#666666">mdi-pencil</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-dialog v-model="showAceEditorModal" fullscreen hide-overlay eager>
      <v-card>
        <v-toolbar dark color="primary">
          <v-btn icon dark @click="closeAceEditor">
            <v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-toolbar-title>{{title}}</v-toolbar-title>
          <v-card-text v-if="editable===false"> Read Only Mode - you won't be able to edit or save changes</v-card-text>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-toolbar-items>
            <v-btn dark text @click="sendEditsToParent">
              {{ closeLabelTxt }}
            </v-btn>
          </v-toolbar-items>
        </v-toolbar>
        <div :id=editorIdX >
          {{ v }}
        </div>
        <div id="test"></div>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import * as ace from '@/assets/js/ace/src-min-noconflict/ace.js';
import * as v from '@/assets/js/ace/vkbeautify.js';
export default {
  name: "AceEditor",
  props:['title', 'editable', 'value', 'originalItem', 'editorIdX'],

  data(){
    return {
      v : "",
      oldItem : this.originalItem,
      showAceEditorModal: false
    }
  },

  computed : {
    closeLabelTxt : function (){
      return this.editable?"Save":"Close Me";
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.v = document.getElementById("textArea_0").value
    document.getElementById("test").innerText = document.getElementById("textArea_0").value
  },
  methods:{
    openInEditor(){
      this.editorId = this.editorIdX;
      this.editor = ace.edit(  this.editorIdX  );
      if( this.editable === false ){
        this.editor.setReadOnly( true );
      }

      //  deprecation fix
      this.editor.$blockScrolling = Infinity;
      //  ignore doctype warnings
      const session = this.editor.getSession();
      session.on("changeAnnotation", () => {
        const a = session.getAnnotations();
        const b = a.slice(0).filter( (item) => item.text.indexOf('DOC') == -1 );
        if(a.length > b.length) session.setAnnotations(b);
      });

      //  editor options
      this.options = this.options || {};

      //  opinionated option defaults
      this.options.maxLines = this.options.maxLines || Infinity;
      this.options.printMargin = this.options.printMargin || false;
      this.options.highlightActiveLine = this.options.highlightActiveLine || false;

      //  hide cursor
      if(this.options.cursor === 'none' || this.options.cursor === false){
        this.editor.renderer.$cursorLayer.element.style.display = 'none';
        delete this.options.cursor;
      }

      //  add missing mode and theme paths
      if(this.options.mode && this.options.mode.indexOf('ace/mode/')===-1) {
        this.options.mode = `ace/mode/${this.options.mode}`;
      }
      if(this.options.theme && this.options.theme.indexOf('ace/theme/')===-1) {
        this.options.theme = 'ace/theme/${this.options.theme}';
      }
      this.editor.setOptions(this.options);
      this.showAceEditorModal = true;
    },

    closeAceEditor(){
      this.showAceEditorModal = false;
    },
    sendEditsToParent(){
      if( this.editor.getReadOnly() === false ){
        this.$emit('editedItem', [ {"editedItem": this.editor.getValue() }, {"originalItem":this.oldItem}]);
      }
      this.showAceEditorModal = false
    },
    reformatContent(){
      let x = this.editor.session.getValue();
      this.editor.session.setValue("");
      x = vkbeautify.xml( x );
      this.editor.session.setValue( x );
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are setting `maxLines` to `Infinity`, by that disabling virtual screen optimization of the editor. `maxLines` is intended for small snippets, less than window height.

Comment: @a user,  ... that did it! Afterwards I run into another issue: after the editor config change, in the Vue modal, the container for the editor had 0 height for some reason so it appeared not to load at all. The container height had to be resolved, but that's minor thing. Now Ace is screaming ;-)